# Bulk Capacitor for Motor Driver

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, mosfet-driver, electrolytic-capacitor

I'm creating a motor driver for a BLDC motor. I was wondering how we can calculate or choose what capacitance we need for our purposes.

We're using the motor driver for a chain drive /transmission system. We pull around 20A and supplying our driver with 36V. Im not sure what other info is needed, but thanks!

Comment: Just go with 220uF or 470uF and start from there. It's doesn't need to be an exact thing.

Comment: We went with a 100uF before and that exploded, so we were wondering if there's a good value. We've seen other people/universities use up to ~3000uF for the same purposes

Comment: That kind of sounds like there are design factors you're overlooking such as transient suppression, snubbers, algorithms, overly long cables, bad layouts, excessively fast switching times, or any other number of things because BLDC motor drives for model aircraft of similar ratings use capacitances that can be reasonably obtained with just a couple of capacitors. You might actually need that much capacitance, but you could probably reduce it if you look at other aspects of your design more carefully.

Comment: When did this 100uF explode? At start up? After some time the motor was running? When turning off the motor? What voltag rating did the 100 uF have?

Comment: The capacitor exploded after running the motor unloaded (100% duty cycle) for an extended duration (didn't time, but let's say a minute). We currently have a 1000uF cap in parallel with a 3300uF (unfortunately the 3300uf cap is connected through wires since we didn't design the PCB we currently have for a large cap). They haven't exploded or anything as of yet with loaded or unloaded test runs.

Answer (score 6):

The bulk capacitor makes sure the supply voltage and/or motor voltage doesn't drop too much in case of current spikes/surges. The capacitors will not contribute for the DC current drawn by the motors.

You should find out what the inrush current / surge current is. For DC motors the inrush current equals the stall current.

Decide what voltage drop you want and approach the capacitor size with 
$$ C = \frac{ i_{inrush} \cdot t_\text{duration on inrush current} }{ V_{drop} }$$.

Answer (score 4):

Low ESR caps are rated for high Ripple current in Amps.

Batteries are far greater capacitance and often very low ESR such as a single 18650 cell ≈  10kF and 50 mohms.

The ripple current you choose depends on the ESR and motor surge current rise time. Choose parts with *[low dissipation factor.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/437185/what-are-the-main-characteristics-of-high-reactive-power-rf-capacitors/437243#437243)*

My rule of thumb is choose Cap Array & Battery and Bridge ESR's much lower than your motor DCR to minimize losses such that it spans a wide spectrum of frequencies generated by the motor pulse load.

This cost of Caps rises with capacitance for values  of  τ = ESR * C << 1us but they do make them for WPT and large motor supplies.

Comment: how do you determine the ripple currents produced by the motor commutations --or do you have to measure these?

Comment: You can model it but depends on the number of phases greatly.

Comment: can you give me an example, say 3 phases?  how would I model it?

Comment: Try searching for the answer

Comment: I have, posting here is what I did after not being to find a satisfactory answer.....it's ok if you don't know....

Comment: I know but too long to explain. It’s ok if you don’t have the skill to ask the right search questions

Comment: Any suggestions on how to phrase the question for the search?

Comment: Sure @jrive  I used **bldc motor driver load capacitor ESR** then first few TI BLDC reference designs discuss all the ESR tradeoffs and show simulation plots,  But 20A motors are probably 200A surges on start so RMS current ratings must be factored with **EMI noise , ripple current and temp rise**  as additional keywords.  then here "around " 720W" maybe add  1kW  or 50A

Comment: result ;  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiI_vfqxfXpAhXLGs0KHY5VD_EQFjAAegQIGBAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fpdf%2Ftiduay9&usg=AOvVaw1-mEj0bnRzohyIPZ3fXwT2  then search ESR and discover why they use low ESR ceramic caps  or re-search using **BLDC 100A low ESR**  or even 200A

Comment: Then you may discover solutions like adding ferrite beads to Gate to reduce drive current ripple and heat rise in Caps from resonance.   a good design should do is choose 3 or 4 different cap values and packages, with resonant frequencies spread across the desired range, and use any many of each as you need to get the desired ESR value. The combined impedance will give us what we want, which is a uniformly low impedance across a wide range of frequencies.

Comment: In the end the ESR of all the caps * current spectrum  oughtt to be less than DCR of motor which dissipates heat much better.    Dielectrics are also better thermal insulators than magnetic parts with DCR.

Comment: Thank you, @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75.  I am aware of ESR in caps and the why's for requiring low ESR types in high ripple current applications.  However, what I am looking for is how to model or calculate the ripple currents that the phase commutations create. I can try to do the math with laplace transforms, superpositioning the commutation phases, but I was wondeing if there is a simpler way that can lead to a rough estimate these.  Thank you.

Comment: I use Falstad simulations for both filter f domain and scope time domain and add the DCR, ESR and vary beta or Gm RON of FET

Comment: @jrive  Imagine your problem is the AC ripple on a power supply that needs to deliver a surge current that is 10x the motor rating. The motor supply LC resonance must be well above the motor Pole frequency with high surge current ability. So it can be reduced to a simple RL+RC series resonant bode plot for ripple and RPM excitation signal on supply then current limit * time needs to be limited by design.

Comment: Put in your own values of Cap + ESR and Motor phase L +DCR then see what RPM causes most ripple current to blow up cap http://tinyurl.com/yd99cwrq  This hypothetical example resonates at 40Hz or 2400 RPM and overheats cap.  The BLDC driver must be capable of driving 10x the motor amps for startup but not thermally continuous. So you can also add ESR of FET to sig sweep gen to simulate leg of H bridge.